# Logo picture for all domain users using GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am trying to apply the company logo to all our users' profile pictures using GPO. We created one share folder with the appropriate permissions and the filename "user.bmp".  This is done by GPO Computer Configuration/Preferences/Windows settings/ Files. created with Replace option and also update option.

While we checking client machines GPO applied successfully but there is no result. Permission level we checked all fine. in the Event Viewer, we found on the warning message.

Event ID: 4098, Group Policy Files

"The computer 'User.bmp' preference item in the 'Logo {5B710835-EEF0-43BE-839A-240DEF208BE8}' Group Policy object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070003 The system cannot find the path specified.' This error was suppressed."

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've tried something like this but I believe it works the same. Is the file location local on the server or domain controller where you set the GPO? If you tell it to use C:\logo.jpg in the path, each system is going to look for logo.jpg to be store on the root of C:

Either copy the file to each server in the path you targeted in the GPO or point it to a share that the systems will have access to. Sysvol would work.

Comment: I have used my GPO and the share location in the Domain controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a file on the client using GPO, the source file location needs to be someplace that the client can access. In many cases this is the sysvol share. For example:

```
\\mydomain.local\SYSVOL\mydomain.local\files\logo.jpg
```

A common mistake is to specify a local file system path instead of a file share path for the source file location. Please check that you have not done this.

The target file location needs to have a local path:

```
c:\icons\logo.jpg
```